# How do "Off-Topic" flags for moderator attention get received?

Tags: support, questions, flags

When I flag a question, I can pick Off Topic, then I can pick a target site, such as programmers. In my history it goes through as **off topic; belongs on Webmaster**.

Is the destination site marked separately? Or is this just the same as if I actually typed **off topic; belongs on Webmaster** in the textarea for other flag reasons?

Additionally, can this be re-used, can I type in **off topic; belongs on ServerFault** in a site that does not have the option for ServerFault ([like Security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/654/please-provide-off-topic-alternative-site-options))? Does this create a convenient button for the Moderators, or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flags to migrate to a site not in one of the pre-selected options will just appear as text to the moderators.

Same as what happens when flags come from users under 3k close level.

No matter the format of your text, they do not get auto-converted to special links or buttons that allow a quick migration trigger. There's still a bit of checking to make sure the suggestion is appropriate.

If you do flag for migration to a site not in the pre-selected slots, it's always extra helpful to add a bit more reasoning as to why it should be migrated as opposed to just closed as off-topic.

Comment: So do they get a convenient button to sites that *are* selected in the list? Does that only happen to users over 3k rep?

Comment: If it's already on the list it's just a normal close vote. From under 3k, it's just text, no vote

Comment: We have a tool that allows us to migrate to *any* site in the SE 2.0 network; given how many sites there are (and bound to be), we are given a free-form text box which we can type some of the site's name and then get a pop up list of where to migrate to.