# Is typing out a canned flag reason equivalent to selecting it?

Tags: support, flags

If I type out a pre-existing flag reason in the *it needs ♦ moderator attention → other* field, does it behave as if I had cast that type of flag? For example:

- If I flag an answer and type out "not an answer" in the reason field, is it treated as a normal NAA flag (e.g., shown to 10k+ users)?
- If I manually enter "invalid flag" outside of the flag queue, does it work? (Say I dismissed a post by upvoting it, but forgot to mark the flags on it invalid before leaving the queue.)
- Is it possible to emit close question flags at 3k+ by typing out "off topic", "not a real question", etc.?

Comment: *Re: my bounty message:* Err, I meant to say that I type **"not constructive"**.

Comment: @JeremyBanks You wouldn't actually need a dev to confirm this (at least the close flag part), just someone with 10k reputation. If they a) see your flag in their queue and b) get a "close question" button, then this applies to close flags too.

Comment: I raised a couple of flags to test this: one default "not constructive" (from a sockpuppet) and one manual "not constructive" (from my account) to compare. [Popular Demand was unable to see either of them](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/not-seeing-the-flag-yet). Not sure what to make of that. (Over-aggressive caching? They still weren't visible four hours later.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks Well, there's a number of things that could have happened. I think as a 10k user you can't see flags on your own posts, nor flags on posts that you've voted on or flagged yourself. Could be that the sockpuppet's flags were suppressed due to low flag weight. Could've been a passing moderator who ruined the experiment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that there is some matching done on the text of the "other" flag that might send it to the 10k queue as well as the mod queue. One such case is described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112469/custom-flag-reasons-visible-in-10k-tools/113488#113488).

For all intents and purposes, entering a message from the "it needs ♦ moderator attention" selection (such as not an answer) in the *other* field is the same as selecting from the list, even for "invalid flag" flags.

Close flags do not work this way. Neither do spam or offensive flags; they're too short to enter into the *other* field anyway.

**The one exception** to this are exact duplicate flags. Custom flags can be converted into close flags if they match a certain format; possibly [this regex](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/772860#772860). This is the default format for close votes from low-rep users:

```
exact duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119125
```

- 10k users can see them
- they are dismissed when someone votes to close
- users with 3k+ rep can use this to dupe flag, but probably shouldn't

Comment: I don't think that's quite right: some "other" flags are not moderator-only, see [Marc's answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113488/134300).

Comment: @JeremyBanks Huh, interesting. Thanks for the link. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/772860#772860

Comment: How would the system know whether I've used the other field, though? I've captured the [traffic](http://pastebin.com/xVR9mTcT) generated by myself flagging this question, and the only thing that seems to get posted is the flag message - same as with normal "not an answer" flags.

Comment: @lunboks I'm not sure how it works in the actual code, but you're using a textbox + a different radio button. That seems like a easy way to test which flag type is being used.

Comment: @lunboks Feel free to flag my answer as "not an answer" written in the "other" field and we can test it out.

Comment: @lunboks It appeared in the 10k queue, so it appears that I stand corrected.

Comment: @AnnaLear Interesting, thanks for helping me confirm that. So presumably blind-flagging as "invalid flag" would work as well. Hmm.

Comment: @lunboks I don't know if it would, since that applies to a specific flag. Hrm. We can test that too, but we'll need someone who's not a mod to flag it again so another user (you?) can dispute it. I'm a bit useless here.

Comment: @AnnaLear I just tried flagging this answer as "invalid flag". I got an error message saying that there are no remaining flags on it. Nothing about not being allowed to do that on account of my below-10k rep.

Comment: flagged for you. btw @anna NaA, VLQ, etc. from a moderator are not binding  – i.e., it does nothing and raises a normal flag. So you could do it as a moderator too. Helps in cases where you warn a user asking them to improve and leave yourself a flag for later. Also, moderators can cast invalid flags from the 10k tools. I've also done this in cases where I've disagreed with the flag, but not enough to ding them 10 pts. It might not be practical to do so on SO, but for SE sites, yeah.

Comment: @yoda Thank you. Flagged as invalid flag again, went through, let's see how this goes.

Comment: @lunboks Looks like those made it to the 10k queue as well.

Comment: @yoda Hmm, interesting. Thanks. I tried finding the "invalid flag" option some time ago and didn't see it there anymore, so I assumed it wasn't available to moderators anymore.

Comment: @anna I didn't see anything in the 10k queue. Are you sure that our queues don't have different cache times?

Comment: Disputed on my end, so yes, that works too. Hahaha yeah, that's probably bad. I would like to make this comment thread the accepted answer.

Comment: @yoda Could be. I definitely saw it in the 10k queue before dismissing the flag(s).

Comment: Nice HTTP traffic testing you did there, @lunboks. That calls for user scripts to add additional migration targets ;-)

Comment: @Arjan I've done some more digging, and it looks like a) flags are really interpreted [based on string matching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112469/custom-flag-reasons-visible-in-10k-tools/113488#113488), and b) what you just said [specifically isn't possible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117162/how-do-off-topic-flags-for-moderator-attention-get-received/117165#117165). Apparently there are some sanity checks, but none that prevent, say, a noob from blindly casting "invalid flag" flags.

Comment: This doesn't apply to close flags for users with close-vote privileges as far as I've seen. I've been monitoring a user with **over 26k rep** who has **never cast a close vote**, but keeps raising "other" flags with "off topic; belongs on Server Fault" or "off topic; belongs on Super User" as the message. It's downright annoying. Worse, I don't think this user knows that flags are declined with a message, because no matter how many times I decline his flags telling him to vote to close, **he doesn't learn**.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Are you sure he's not using the "Other" flag field?

Comment: @Anna: I said that he is. Perhaps I simply misread this question or your answer :|

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Oh, sorry. I missed that. You could leave him a comment or send a message?

Comment: I guess I'll send him a mod message then.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is **no**. According to dev Marc Gravell in chat:

> No, it isn't. Each template has an associated "what was this" marker, and also a "does this suggest user suspension" marker, that we use for tracking. But it isn't a huge difference, and no-one is going to be upset; it is *almost* the same.

<sub>(I formatted Marc's chatspeak; original text is [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/mso119125).)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I've compared the form data sent for standard flags, custom flags and votes to close. Standard and custom flags submit different data to different URLs so it is possible that they are handled differently.

#### Flagging as Not Constructive (<3Kr)

```
/posts/N/vote/6
```

```
isForFlagging=true
close-reason-id=3
duplicate-question-id=
```

#### Flagging as Other: "not constructive" (≥3Kr)

```
/messages/inform-moderator-about-post/N
```

```
msg=not+constructive
```

#### Voting to Close as Not Constructive (≥3Kr)

```
/posts/N/vote/6
```

```
isForFlagging=false
close-reason-id=3
duplicate-question-id=
```