# Help to close a very old question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, vote-to-close

The question [How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array) mentions right in the text of question that it is a duplicate of [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c) (strangely it was a moderator who added the text but he did not close the question, maybe he was not a mod at the time)

This question is the first result on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=c#%20hex%20string%20to%20byte%20array) (the older duplicate is number 2). The reason I make such a big deal is this question has no mention of [SoapHexBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary.aspx) which really is the way it should be done, instead of trying to loop through the text like everyone else does. The duplicate question has SoapHexBinary as the second most voted answer, the duplicate also has a [list of benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624379/80274) comparing the various methods.

Comment: I think you normally flag such a post for moderator attention.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You can't flag to close when you have vote to close rights, it just brings you to the vote to close window when you bring up the flag page

Comment: @ScottChamberlain exactly, so flag it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - vote to close then flag with the custom reason to explain that you don't think it'll get the necessary views to be closed by the community.

Comment: Well, there's just one vote missing now. Anybody? And, @ScottChamberlain casper was indeed not yet a mod when he edited that one. Edit: Mission accomplished.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain [You can still dupe-flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119125/is-typing-out-a-canned-flag-reason-equivalent-to-selecting-it/119126#119126) if you really want to. If you stick to the format, it'll show up to 10k users and everything.

Comment: Related: [Is flagging to close old questions best practice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123455/is-flagging-to-close-old-questions-best-practice)

Comment: [You should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)  Only ***exact*** dupes, aka *reposts*, should be flagged for mod attention, imho.  Sort-of dupes can be handled by consensus closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have given the final close vote on the question in consideration.

What you would normally do in a situation like this, is flag it for a moderator, with a custom description saying something like `exact duplicate of post https://stackoverflow.com/q/xxx`.

Once you get one person to vote for it, it will appear in the [tools / close](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=close&daterange=today) tab in the moderator tools section, where other 10K+ users and moderators can close it as well.

Now, obviously this isn't foolproof, so you do have another option.
You can edit the question to provide a link to the duplicate (which was already done, admittedly), and hopefully that will bump the question enough to get it closed.

As @DanielFischer has pointed out, you can also post a link into a popular [chat](https://stackoverflow.com/chat) room, and hope it gets attention this way.

If all else fails, just post right here on meta, and we can do the dirty work!

Comment: Dropping a link in the Tavern or so is also promising.